# Facebook FQL error in Node.js HTTPS GET

Tags: facebook, node.js

I'm using `node.js` to get the facebook friends of a logged in user with a valid facebook AccessToken.

I'm using the `node.js` https module, to do that with this options:

```
var query = 'q=SELECT uid, name, is_app_user FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me()) and is_app_user=1';
var options = {
    host: 'graph.facebook.com',
    port: 443,
    path: 'fql?' + encodeURI(query) + '&method=GET&metadata=true&format=json&access_token=' + accessToken
};
```

sometimes I can get the data with my friends, but sometime i'm getting an error message from facebook that said Invalid URL.

My facebook application is in Sandbox mode and my server ip is in application whitelist

Any ideas why this is happens?

Thanks!

Comment: I've been having the same error when using [my FQL module](https://github.com/hughsk/fql-node) lately, but I'm almost certain it has nothing to with the URL - the tests I've written work some times, other times they don't. It might be a rate limit or, more likely, a bug on Facebook's end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I changed the `path: 'fql?'...` to `path: '/fql?'...` with the `/` at the beginning..